# How can I make clear a general React component use-cases

Tags: reactjs

I have a general `<Row>` component and I want to make clear in some places what this Row presents, like row of pictures/articles etc....

How should I do that without making a mess in my code by additing too many notes or ids I don't use?

should it be done as following?

```js
        {/* img of ..... */}
     <Row id='img_.....'>
          <img src={imageUrl} alt={`image of ${name}`} />
        </Row>
```